# Why is my aside element not being styled?

Tags: html, css

This site is for a class project. all the aside elements are working on the other pages except this one. for the full site, click [here](https://project3-adame-shanecadame.c9users.io/HTML/index.html) I've tried time after time trying to figure out what is wrong, but I can't figure it out... I'm sure it is something uber-simple, and i'm sure I'm overlooking it and overthinking it. Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

```css
a:active, a:hover {
 color: white;
}

a:link, a:visited {
 color: #c16202;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Quattrocento'
}

body {
    font: 16/26px 'Quattrocento Sans', Sans-Serif;
    color: #241010;
  }

html {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

.main aside {
    border-top: 20px solid #e1a86f;
    background-color: #f0c646;
    padding: 0px 5% 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #aaa;
   }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  
  
    .main article {
        float: right;
        width: 60%;
    }

    .main aside {
        float: left;
        width: 27%;
        position: relative;
    }
}

> Blockquote
```

```html
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main wrapper clearfix">

                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h1 id="hw">Welcome</h1>
                        <p>Carlsbad Caverns National Park is a United States National Park in the Guadalupe Mountains of southeastern New Mexico. The primary attraction of the park is the show cave, Carlsbad Cavern. Carlsbad Caverns National Park is open every day of the year except Thanksgiving, Christmas, and New Year's Day. Visitors to the cave can hike in on their own via the natural entrance or take an elevator from the visitor center.</p>
                        <p>The park entrance is located on US Highway 62/180, approximately 18 miles (29 km) southwest of Carlsbad, New Mexico. Carlsbad Caverns National Park participates in the Junior Ranger Program. The park has two entries on the National Register of Historic Places: The Caverns Historic District and the Rattlesnake Springs Historic District. Approximately two thirds of the park has been set aside as a wilderness area, helping to ensure no future changes will be made to the habitat.</p>
                        <p>Carlsbad Cavern includes a large cave chamber, the Big Room, a natural limestone chamber that is almost 4,000 feet (1,220 m) long, 625 feet (191 m) wide, and 255 feet (78 m) high at the highest point. It is the fifth largest chamber in North America and the twenty-eighth largest in the world.</p>
                    </header>
                    <section>
                        <div class="standout">
                        <h2 id="ht"><a href="tours.html">Tours</a></h2>
                        <p>Before you visit Carlsbad Caverns, read about the different tours available. Tours include Kings Palace, Left Hand Tunnel, Hall of the White Giant, Slaughter Canyon Cave, Spider Cave, The Big Room and the Lower Cave.</p>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <th>
                                </th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="tours.html#lht"><img class="tpic"src="\images\lht.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>Left Hand Tunnel Tour</span></a><br>Those who want to experience some of the most striking scenery will do well to…</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><a href="tours.html#ne"><img class="tpic" src="\images\ne.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>Natural Entrance Self-Guided Tour</span></a><br>Those in good physical health will enjoy the Natural Entrance Self-Guided Tour.…
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="tours.html#sc"><img class ="tpic" src="\images\sc.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>The Spider Cave Tour</span></a><br>The Spider Cave Tour is strenuous and interesting enough that even experienced…</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="tours.html#scc"><img class="tpic" src="\images\scc.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>Slaughter Canyon Cave Tour</span></a><br>Unlike many of the caves in the Carlsbad Caverns National Park, Slaughter Cave…</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="\tours.html#br"><img class="tpic" src="\images\br.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>Big Room Self-Guided Tour</span></a><br>The Big Room Tour is one of the easiest of the tours available at Carlsbad Caverns.…</p>

                                    </div>
                                   </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="tours.html#hwg"><img class="tpic" src="\images\hwg.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>Hall of the White Giant Tour</span></a><br>There are few places left where one can have a real adventure. The Hall of the…</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="tours.html#kp"><img class="tpic" src="\images\kp.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>Kings Palace Tour</span><br></a>Some cavern features are so large that they seem almost manufactured. Kings Palace,…
</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="tours.html#lc"><img class="tpic" src="\images\lc.jpg"></img>
                                    <div class="ttext">
                                            <p><span>Lower Cave Tour</span></a><br>The 3-hour long Lower Cave Tour may be just what adventurous souls are seeking…</p>
</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <h1 id="hh">History</h1>
                        <p>The history of the Carlsbad Caverns, like most stories, can be understood from different perspectives. The modern history of the caves starts with them being set aside as national treasures and as part of the National Park system in the early 20th Century. Prior to that era, the Mexicans and, before them, the Spanish ruled the area. The Native Americans left their mark, as well, with some of the artifacts found in the area dating back as far as 14,000 years. If one takes the geological perspective, the history of these caves spans back as far as 280 million years, when New Mexico looked more like the coastal US.</p>
                        <a href="aboutus.html">Learn more...</a>
                        <h1 id="hti">Tourist information</h1>

                        <p>Carlsbad Caverns sees an average of 407,211 visitors every year. The highest attendance seen in a year was 876,500 visitors in 1976.[15] As of 2011, a total 41,654,278 visitors have entered the park. Peak visitation typically occurs on the weekends following Memorial Day and the Fourth of July. Free admittance for self-guided tours is often granted on holidays such as Martin Luther King, Jr. weekend, National Park Week, and Veterans Day weekend.[16] Camping is permitted in the back country of the park, but a permit is required from the visitor center.</p>
                        <p>One of the extra events hosted by the park is the viewing of a bat flight. A program is given in the early evening at the amphitheater near the main entrance prior to the start of the flight, which varies with the sunset time. Flight programs are scheduled from Memorial Day weekend through the middle of October.[17] Optimal viewing normally occurs in July and August with the arrival of the bat pups in addition to the normal migratory bats. Morning programs are also hosted pre-dawn to witness the return of bats into the cave. Once a year, a bat flight breakfast is held where visitors can eat breakfast at the park prior to the morning return of bats.</p>
                        <p>At various times throughout the year, star parties are hosted by the park at night. Rangers host informational programs on the celestial night sky and telescopes are also made available. These parties are often held in conjunction with special astronomical events, such as a transit of Venus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </article>
                
                <aside>
                    <h3>Contents</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html#hw">Welcome</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#ht">Tours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#hh">History</a></li>
                        <li href="index.html#hti">Tourist Information</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                
            </div> <!-- #main -->
        </div> <!-- #main-container -->
                
        <div class="footer-container">
            <footer class="wrapper">
                <h3>footer</h3>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Comment: Probably because your HTML is in valid. Run it through a validator.

Comment: the page to which you linked is missing the stylesheet...

Comment: `<li href="index.html#hti">Tourist Information</a></li>` You forgot an opening `<a>` tag there

Comment: @Decaspex, Thanks. done, but it still isn't working...

Comment: When you have invalid HTML most browsers will attempt to correct it by moving elements around etc. so you need to fix that first.